# asn.1 parser in C/Python

Tags: python, c, parsing, asn.1

I am looking for a solution to parse asn.1 spec files and generate a decoder from those.

Ideally I would like to work with Python modules, but if nothing is available I would use C/C++ libraries and interface them with Python with the plethora of solutions out there.

In the past I have been using pyasn1 and building everything by hand but that has become too unwieldly.

I have also looked superficially to libtasn1 and asn1c. The first one had problems parsing even the simplest of files. The second has a good parser but generating C code for decoding seems too complex; the solution worked well with straightforward specs but choked on complex ones.

Any other good alternatives I may have overlooked?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Never tried them but:

- [asn1c](http://asn1c.sourceforge.net/)
- [snacc](http://svn.debian.org/wsvn/collab-maint/deb-maint/snacc/)

Both seems to do what you want (C, not Python).

Comment: snacc went under the radar for me. I will check it out. Thanks!

Comment: asn1c has been the best option so far.

Answer (score 13):

I wrote such parser a few years ago. It generates python classes for pyasn1 library. I used in on ericsson doc to make parser for their CDRs.

I'll try posting the code here now.

```
import sys
from pyparsing import *

OpenBracket = Regex("[({]").suppress()
CloseBracket = Regex("[)}]").suppress()

def Enclose(val):
  return OpenBracket + val + CloseBracket

def SetDefType(typekw):
  def f(a, b, c):
    c["defType"] = typekw
  return f

def NoDashes(a, b, c):
  return c[0].replace("-", "_")

def DefineTypeDef(typekw, typename, typedef):
  return typename.addParseAction(SetDefType(typekw)).setResultsName("definitionType") - \
    Optional(Enclose(typedef).setResultsName("definition"))



SizeConstraintBodyOpt = Word(nums).setResultsName("minSize") - \
  Optional(Suppress(Literal("..")) - Word(nums + "n").setResultsName("maxSize"))

SizeConstraint = Group(Keyword("SIZE").suppress() - Enclose(SizeConstraintBodyOpt)).setResultsName("sizeConstraint")

Constraints = Group(delimitedList(SizeConstraint)).setResultsName("constraints")

DefinitionBody = Forward()

TagPrefix = Enclose(Word(nums).setResultsName("tagID")) - Keyword("IMPLICIT").setResultsName("tagFormat")

OptionalSuffix = Optional(Keyword("OPTIONAL").setResultsName("isOptional"))
JunkPrefix = Optional("--F--").suppress()
AName = Word(alphanums + "-").setParseAction(NoDashes).setResultsName("name")

SingleElement = Group(JunkPrefix - AName - Optional(TagPrefix) - DefinitionBody.setResultsName("typedef") - OptionalSuffix)

NamedTypes = Dict(delimitedList(SingleElement)).setResultsName("namedTypes")

SetBody = DefineTypeDef("Set", Keyword("SET"), NamedTypes)
SequenceBody = DefineTypeDef("Sequence", Keyword("SEQUENCE"), NamedTypes)
ChoiceBody = DefineTypeDef("Choice", Keyword("CHOICE"), NamedTypes)

SetOfBody = (Keyword("SET") + Optional(SizeConstraint) + Keyword("OF")).setParseAction(SetDefType("SetOf")) + Group(DefinitionBody).setResultsName("typedef")
SequenceOfBody = (Keyword("SEQUENCE") + Optional(SizeConstraint) + Keyword("OF")).setParseAction(SetDefType("SequenceOf")) + Group(DefinitionBody).setResultsName("typedef")

CustomBody = DefineTypeDef("constructed", Word(alphanums + "-").setParseAction(NoDashes), Constraints)
NullBody = DefineTypeDef("Null", Keyword("NULL"), Constraints)

OctetStringBody = DefineTypeDef("OctetString", Regex("OCTET STRING"), Constraints)
IA5StringBody = DefineTypeDef("IA5String", Keyword("IA5STRING"), Constraints)

EnumElement = Group(Word(printables).setResultsName("name") - Enclose(Word(nums).setResultsName("value")))
NamedValues = Dict(delimitedList(EnumElement)).setResultsName("namedValues")
EnumBody = DefineTypeDef("Enum", Keyword("ENUMERATED"), NamedValues)

BitStringBody = DefineTypeDef("BitString", Keyword("BIT") + Keyword("STRING"), NamedValues)

DefinitionBody << (OctetStringBody | SetOfBody | SetBody | ChoiceBody | SequenceOfBody | SequenceBody | EnumBody | BitStringBody | IA5StringBody | NullBody | CustomBody)

Definition = AName - Literal("::=").suppress() - Optional(TagPrefix) - DefinitionBody

Definitions = Dict(ZeroOrMore(Group(Definition)))

pf = Definitions.parseFile(sys.argv[1])

TypeDeps = {}
TypeDefs = {}

def SizeConstraintHelper(size):
  s2 = s1 = size.get("minSize")
  s2 = size.get("maxSize", s2)
  try:
    return("constraint.ValueSizeConstraint(%s, %s)" % (int(s1), int(s2)))
  except ValueError:
    pass

ConstraintMap = {
  'sizeConstraint' : SizeConstraintHelper,
}

def ConstraintHelper(c):
  result = []
  for key, value in c.items():
    r = ConstraintMap[key](value)
    if r:
      result.append(r)
  return result

def GenerateConstraints(c, ancestor, element, level=1):
  result = ConstraintHelper(c)
  if result:
    return [ "subtypeSpec = %s" % " + ".join(["%s.subtypeSpec" % ancestor] + result) ]
  return []

def GenerateNamedValues(definitions, ancestor, element, level=1):
  result = [ "namedValues = namedval.NamedValues(" ]
  for kw in definitions:
    result.append("  ('%s', %s)," % (kw["name"], kw["value"]))
  result.append(")")
  return result

OptMap = {
  False: "",
  True: "Optional",
}

def GenerateNamedTypesList(definitions, element, level=1):
  result = []
  for val in definitions:
    name = val["name"]
    typename = None

    isOptional = bool(val.get("isOptional"))

    subtype = []
    constraints = val.get("constraints")
    if constraints:
      cg = ConstraintHelper(constraints)
      subtype.append("subtypeSpec=%s" % " + ".join(cg))
    tagId = val.get("tagID")
    if tagId:
      subtype.append("implicitTag=tag.Tag(tag.tagClassContext, tag.tagFormatConstructed, %s)" % tagId)

    if subtype:
      subtype = ".subtype(%s)" % ", ".join(subtype)
    else:
      subtype = ""

    cbody = []
    if val["defType"] == "constructed":
      typename = val["typedef"]
      element["_d"].append(typename)
    elif val["defType"] == "Null":
      typename = "univ.Null"
    elif val["defType"] == "SequenceOf":
      typename = "univ.SequenceOf"
      print val.items()
      cbody = [ "  componentType=%s()" % val["typedef"]["definitionType"] ]
    elif val["defType"] == "Choice":
      typename = "univ.Choice"
      indef = val.get("definition")
      if indef:
        cbody = [ "  %s" % x for x in GenerateClassDefinition(indef, name, typename, element) ]
    construct = [ "namedtype.%sNamedType('%s', %s(" % (OptMap[isOptional], name, typename), ")%s)," % subtype ]
    if not cbody:
      result.append("%s%s%s" % ("  " * level, construct[0], construct[1]))
    else:
      result.append("  %s" % construct[0])
      result.extend(cbody)
      result.append("  %s" % construct[1])
  return result



def GenerateNamedTypes(definitions, ancestor, element, level=1):
  result = [ "componentType = namedtype.NamedTypes(" ]
  result.extend(GenerateNamedTypesList(definitions, element))
  result.append(")")
  return result


defmap = {
  'constraints' : GenerateConstraints,
  'namedValues' : GenerateNamedValues,
  'namedTypes' : GenerateNamedTypes,
}

def GenerateClassDefinition(definition, name, ancestor, element, level=1):
  result = []
  for defkey, defval in definition.items():
    if defval:
      fn = defmap.get(defkey)
      if fn:
        result.extend(fn(defval, ancestor, element, level))
  return ["  %s" % x for x in result]

def GenerateClass(element, ancestor):
  name = element["name"]

  top = "class %s(%s):" % (name, ancestor)
  definition = element.get("definition")
  body = []
  if definition:
    body = GenerateClassDefinition(definition, name, ancestor, element)
  else:
    typedef = element.get("typedef")
    if typedef:
      element["_d"].append(typedef["definitionType"])
      body.append("  componentType = %s()" % typedef["definitionType"])
      szc = element.get('sizeConstraint')
      if szc:
        body.extend(GenerateConstraints({ 'sizeConstraint' : szc }, ancestor, element))

  if not body:
    body.append("  pass")

  TypeDeps[name] = list(frozenset(element["_d"]))

  return "\n".join([top] + body)

StaticMap = {
  "Null" : "univ.Null",
  "Enum" : "univ.Enumerated",
  "OctetString" : "univ.OctetString",
  "IA5String" : "char.IA5String",
  "Set" : "univ.Set",
  "Sequence" : "univ.Sequence",
  "Choice" : "univ.Choice",
  "SetOf" : "univ.SetOf",
  "BitString" : "univ.BitString",
  "SequenceOf" : "univ.SequenceOf",
}

def StaticConstructor(x):
  x["_d"] = []
  if x["defType"] == "constructed":
    dt = x["definitionType"]
    x["_d"].append(dt)
  else:
    dt = StaticMap[x["defType"]]
  return GenerateClass(x, dt)


for element in pf:
  TypeDefs[element["name"]] = StaticConstructor(element)

while TypeDefs:
  ready = [ k for k, v in TypeDeps.items() if len(v) == 0 ]
  if not ready:
    x = list()
    for a in TypeDeps.values():
      x.extend(a)
    x = frozenset(x) - frozenset(TypeDeps.keys())

    print TypeDefs

    raise ValueError, sorted(x)

  for t in ready:
    for v in TypeDeps.values():
      try:
        v.remove(t)
      except ValueError:
        pass

    del TypeDeps[t]
    print TypeDefs[t]
    print
    print

    del TypeDefs[t]
```

This will take a file with syntax, similar to this one:

```
CarrierInfo ::= OCTET STRING (SIZE(2..3))
ChargeAreaCode ::= OCTET STRING (SIZE(3))
ChargeInformation ::= OCTET STRING (SIZE(2..33))
ChargedParty ::= ENUMERATED

 (chargingOfCallingSubscriber  (0),
  chargingOfCalledSubscriber   (1),
  noCharging                   (2))
ChargingOrigin ::= OCTET STRING (SIZE(1))
Counter ::= OCTET STRING (SIZE(1..4))
Date ::= OCTET STRING (SIZE(3..4))
```

You will need to add this line on top of the generated file:

```
from pyasn1.type import univ, namedtype, namedval, constraint, tag, char
```

And name the result defs.py. Then, I attached a bunch of prettyprinters to the defs (if you don't have just skip it)

```
import defs, parsers

def rplPrettyOut(self, value):
  return repr(self.decval(value))

for name in dir(parsers):
  if (not name.startswith("_")) and hasattr(defs, name):
    target = getattr(defs, name)
    target.prettyOut = rplPrettyOut
    target.decval = getattr(parsers, name)
```

Then, it's down to:

```
  def ParseBlock(self, block):
    while block and block[0] != '\x00':
      result, block = pyasn1.codec.ber.decoder.decode(block, asn1Spec=parserimp.defs.CallDataRecord())
      yield result
```

If you're still interested I'll put the code somewhere. In fact, I'll put it somewhere in any case - but if you're interested just let me know and I'll point you there.

Comment: I might interested in using this in an open source project (http://packages.python.org/DendroPy/). Is this code public-domain or available under a relatively relaxed open source license such as BSD, MIT etc.?

Answer (score 3):

I'm the author of LEPL, a parser written in Python, and what you want to do is one of the things on my "TODO" list.

I will not be doing this soon, but you might consider using LEPL to construct your solution because:

1 - it's a pure Python solution (which makes life simpler)

2 - it can already parse binary data as well as text, so you would only need to use a single tool - the same parser that you would use to parse the ASN1 spec would then be used to parse the binary data

The main downsides are that:

1 - it's a fairly new package, so it may be buggier than some, and the support community is not that large

2 - it is restricted to Python 2.6 and up (and the binary parser only works with Python 3 and up).

For more information, please see http://www.acooke.org/lepl - in particular,for binary parsing see the relevant section of the manual (I cannot link directly to that as Stack Overflow seems to think I am spamming)

Andrew

PS  The main reason this is not something I have already started is that the ASN 1 specs are not freely available, as far as I know.  If you have access to them, and it is not illegal(!), a copy would be greatly appreciated (unfortunately I am currently working on another project, so this would still take time to implement, but it would help me get this working sooner...).

Comment: LEPL looks certainly interesting, but on the short term part of my needs are compatibility with Python 2.4.

Answer (score 2):

There is an [ANTLR ASN.1 grammar](http://www.antlr.org/grammar/1231433381400/ASN.g); using ANTLR, you should be able to make an ASN.1 parser out of it. Generating code for pyasn1 is left as an exercise to the poster :-)

Comment: The quote from the link: "The grammar is by far not complete. I have no experience in ANTLR".

Answer (score 2):

I have experience with [pyasn1](http://pyasn1.sourceforge.net/) and it's enough to parse quite complex grammars. A grammar is expressed with python structure, so no need to run code generator.

Comment: The problem with pyasn1 is that the data structures have to be written manually. This is ok for small asn.1 definitions. But not for huge ones.

Answer (score 1):

I have done a similar job using asn1c and building around it a Pyrex extension. The wrapped structure is described in [3GPP TS 32.401](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/32401.htm).

With Pyrex you can write a wrapper thick enough to convert between native Python data types and the correct ASN.1 representations (wrapper generators, such SWIG, tend to not perform complex operations on the type). The wrapper I wrote also tracked the ownership of the underlying C data structures (e.g. accessing to a sub-structure, a Python object was returned, but there was no copy of the underlying data, only reference sharing).

The wrapper was eventually written in a kind of semi-automatic way, but because that has been my only job with ASN.1 I never did the step of completely automatize the code generation.

You can try to use other Python-C wrappers and perform a completely automatic conversion: the job would be less, but then you would move complexity (and repetitive error-prone operations) to the structure users: for this reason I preferred the Pyrex way. asn1c was definitely a good choice.

Comment: The asn1 definition I have is pretty long and it seems complex. The code that asn1c generates seems to have problems with this file and the idea is not to have to debug another tool.

Answer (score 1):

I recently created the Python package called [asn1tools](http://asn1tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which compiles an ASN.1 specification into Python objects, which can be used to encode and decode messages.

```
>>> import asn1tools
>>> foo = asn1tools.compile_file('tests/files/foo.asn')
>>> encoded = foo.encode('Question', {'id': 1, 'question': 'Is 1+1=3?'})
>>> encoded
bytearray(b'0\x0e\x02\x01\x01\x16\x09Is 1+1=3?')
>>> foo.decode('Question', encoded)
{'id': 1, 'question': 'Is 1+1=3?'}
```